# How to save an updated many-to-many collection on detached Entity Framework 4.1 POCO entity

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1, ef-code-first

For the last few days I'm trying to properly update my POCO entities. More specific, it's many-to-many relationship collections.

I've three database tables:
Author - *1..n* - AuthorBooks - *n..1* - Books.

Translates to two POCO entities:
An *Author* entity with a *Books* collection and *Book* entity with a *Authors* collection.

**Case**

When I have one active DbContext, retrieve a Book entity, add an Author and call SaveChanges(), the changes are properly send to the database. All fine so far.

However I've a desktop application with limited DbContext lifetime, as displayed in code fragments below.

```
public Book GetBook(int id)
{
   using (var context = new LibariesContext())
   {
      return context.Books
         .Include(b => b.Authors)
         .AsNoTracking()
         .Single(b => b.BookId == id);
   }
}

public Author GetAuthor(int id)
{
   using (var context = new LibariesContext())
   {
      return context.Authors
         .AsNoTracking()
         .Single(a => a.AuthorId == id);
   }
}
```

A simplified example of various of my business logic methods, wraps it together:

```
public void BusinessLogicMethods()
{
   Book book = GetBook(id: 1);
   Author author = GetAuthor(id: 1);

   book.Name = "New book title";
   book.Authors.Add(author);
   SaveBook(book);
}

public void SaveBook(Book book)
{
   using (var context = new LibariesContext())
   {
      context.Entry(book).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
      context.SaveChanges();
   }
}
```

Unfortunately the only thing that is really saved here, is the name of the book. The new author was not saved, neither was an Exception thrown.

**Questions**

- What's the best way to save the collection of a detached entity?
- Any workaround for this issue?

Comment: Since there is no change to the author object i guess EF is not adding another record. Try to copy the values into a new Author object and then perform a save to make sure that when saving the book entity your author gets created.

Comment: @Rajesh Thanks for you're reply. It's however not the intention to add another Author record. It's intented to add an AuthorBooks record.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm new to EF 4.1 too, and if I understand your question correctly, I think I ran into this nonsense over the weekend. After trying every approach under the sun to get the entries to update, I found a mantra here on SO (I can't find it any more) and turned it into a generic extension method. So now, after the line:

```
book.Authors.Add(author);
```

I would add the line:

```
context.UpdateManyToMany(book, b => b.Authors)
```

You might need to restructure your code to make this happen.

Anyway... here's the extension method I wrote. Let me know if it works (no guarantees!!!)

```
    public static void UpdateManyToMany<TSingle, TMany>(
        this DbContext ctx,
        TSingle localItem,
        Func<TSingle, ICollection<TMany>> collectionSelector)
        where TSingle : class
        where TMany : class
    {
        DbSet<TSingle> localItemDbSet = ctx.Set(typeof(TSingle)).Cast<TSingle>();
        DbSet<TMany> manyItemDbSet = ctx.Set(typeof(TMany)).Cast<TMany>();

        ObjectContext objectContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter) ctx).ObjectContext;
        ObjectSet<TSingle> tempSet = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TSingle>();
        IEnumerable<string> localItemKeyNames = tempSet.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name);

        var localItemKeysArray = localItemKeyNames.Select(kn => typeof(TSingle).GetProperty(kn).GetValue(localItem, null));

        localItemDbSet.Load();

        TSingle dbVerOfLocalItem = localItemDbSet.Find(localItemKeysArray.ToArray());
        IEnumerable<TMany> localCol = collectionSelector(localItem)?? Enumerable.Empty<TMany>();
        ICollection<TMany> dbColl = collectionSelector(dbVerOfLocalItem);
        dbColl.Clear();

        ObjectSet<TMany> tempSet1 = objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TMany>();
        IEnumerable<string> collectionKeyNames = tempSet1.EntitySet.ElementType.KeyMembers.Select(k => k.Name);

        var selectedDbCats = localCol
            .Select(c => collectionKeyNames.Select(kn => typeof (TMany).GetProperty(kn).GetValue(c, null)).ToArray())
            .Select(manyItemDbSet.Find);
        foreach (TMany xx in selectedDbCats)
        {
            dbColl.Add(xx);
        }
        ctx.Entry(dbVerOfLocalItem).CurrentValues.SetValues(localItem);
    }
```

Comment: Doesn't work yet.. but trying to figure out your code now. Did your case also involve a detached entity?

Comment: Brilliant solution, it works like a charm. The only I needed to do is, save your extension method and replace the 'context.Entry(book).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;' line in SaveBook() method by the 'context.UpdateManyToMany(book, b => b.Authors)' call. How did you figure this all out?

Comment: "How did you figure this all out?": Very painfully over the course of about 7 hours last Friday night when I would have preferred to be in bed. As I said, a non generic version of what's happening above exists somewhere on SO (frustratingly, I can't find it now)... as we need to do this more than once, the "only" option was to write the method above ;)

Comment: Very, very nice!! Just had it included in our main application, finally the bug solved. Cool you've shared this solution, can imagine many more people benefit from your extension method! And after all, this generic solution is probably much better than a non-generic one! Thanks again.

Comment: A splendid solution spender, however, it does seem to run into some nasty problems where `TSingle` and `TMany` are derived types. Can you shed any light on this?

Comment: @Monty : You might be interested in this question that my colleague posted. It's effective questioning the sanity of this approach (providing the non-generic approach from which this answer was based). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8417824/entity-framework-4-1-updating-many-to-many-relationships-is-this-the-right-way

Comment: @spender Thanks for the link, interesting read. Discovered myself some 'issues' too. The first being a case when multiple many-to-many collections are included on an entity. The second, as mentioned in the given post, lazy loading being turned off. However, I think, such a generic approach is really unevitable for any average sized business application...

Answer (score 1):

I came across this question when I was attempting to solve the same problem.  In the end I took a different approach which seems to be working.  I had to end up exposing a "state" property on the entities and have the calling context set the state of the entities within the object graph.

This reduces the overhead on the web service/data context side to have to determine what's changed, given that the graph could be populated by any number of query permeation.  There's also a NuGet package called GraphDiff which might work for you as well(details in the link below).

Anyhow, full details here: http://sanderstechnology.com/2013/solving-the-detached-many-to-many-problem-with-the-entity-framework/12505/