# Entity Framework 4.1. Updating many-to-many relationships. Is this the right way?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1

The code below works, however, I suspect that I'm missing something. Is there a 'better' way?

```
    private void UpdateNew(MarketProduct marketproduct)
    {
        context.MarketCategories.Load();
        MarketProduct dbProd = context.MarketProducts.Find(marketproduct.Id);
        dbProd.Categories.Clear();
        foreach (var c in marketproduct.Categories ?? Enumerable.Empty<MarketCategory>())
        {
            var cc = context.MarketCategories.Find(c.Id);
            dbProd.Categories.Add(cc);
        }
        context.Entry(dbProd).CurrentValues.SetValues(marketproduct);
    }
```

I thought it would be possible to do this without using `Find`

Answer (score 1):

You have three database queries: 1) `context.MarketCategories.Load()` (hopefully the category table is small, otherwise this would be a no-go as it loads the whole table into memory), 2) `...Find` and 3) `dbProd.Categories.Clear()`: Here must be a lazy loading involved, otherwise this would crash because `dbProd.Categories` would be `null`.

An alternative to update with a single database query is the following:

```
private void UpdateNew(MarketProduct marketproduct)
{
    MarketProduct dbProd = context.MarketProducts
        .Include(p => p.Categories)
        .Single(p => p.Id == marketproduct.Id);

    var categories = marketproduct.Categories 
                     ?? Enumerable.Empty<MarketCategory>();
    foreach (var category in categories)
    {
        if (!dbProd.Categories.Any(c => c.Id == category.Id))
        {
            // means: category is new
            context.MarketCategories.Attach(category);
            dbProd.Categories.Add(category);
        }
    }
    foreach (var category in dbProd.Categories.ToList())
    {
        if (!categories.Any(c => c.Id == category.Id))
            // means: category has been removed
            dbProd.Categories.Remove(category);
    }

    context.Entry(dbProd).CurrentValues.SetValues(marketproduct);

    // context.SaveChanges() somewhere
}
```

Comment: The idea of the Load at the start is to get all categories (only a handful will ever be needed) into the context, AFAIK this will prevent Find from hitting the database in the loop. also AFAIK Clear won't cause a db hit until SaveChanges is called. Yes, the marketproduct object graph is detached.

Comment: @Tom: Your understanding is correct. If the catogories table is small, then your solution is fine, I'd say. You could still use `Include` to avoid the lazy loading, but that's not that important for performance (and even not necessarily better). Consider my answer as an alternative solution then in case you have a BIG table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could just do this:

```
var dbProd = context.MarketProducts.Find(marketproduct.Id);
dbProd.Categories = dbProd.Categories
    .Union(marketproduct.Categories).ToList();

context.SaveChanges();
```

The `Union()` call will keep any existing products, add new ones, and update ones that overlap. Since your navigation property `Categories` is probably defined as an `ICollection<Category>` you have to use the `ToList()` extension method during assignment.

Comment: Would be very cool if something this short would work, but... It doesn't handle the case that categories have been removed and `marketProduct` and its categories must not be detached entities, otherwise you'll get duplications of categories in the database. (I think it is detached, otherwise I would not understand why he uses the `Find` in the loop instead of directly adding `c`.)

Comment: I was assuming the the `marketproduct` object graph was attached. And yes, to handle removed entities you'd need to `Clear()` the list first. I think then you could still safely `Union()` the sets. I'm doing something similar although simpler in one of my applications.

Comment: I was expecting something like this to work too, but it doesn't seem to.